# Is there a way in R to fill up a dataframe with missing values just like excel vlookup? (SOLVED)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df1 which is like this:

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Cabbage | Vegetable |
| Apple | NA |
| Orange | Fruit |
| Cabbage | NA |
| Toy | Misc |
| Apple | NA |

Currently, the dataframe only has the category for the first time the Name appeared.

However, I would like to fill the categories within the dataframe to make it like this based on the Name:

| Name | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Cabbage | Vegetable |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Orange | Fruit |
| Cabbage | Vegetable |
| Toy | Misc |
| Apple | Fruit |

Would appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 5):

We can use `left_join` from dplyr package

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  left_join(dat %>% 
              drop_na() %>% 
              unique(), by = "Name") %>% 
  select(Name,
         Category = Category.y)
     Name  Category
1   Apple     Fruit
2  Banana     Fruit
3 Cabbage Vegetable
4   Apple     Fruit
5  Orange     Fruit
6 Cabbage Vegetable
7     Toy      Misc
8   Apple     Fruit
```

Consider this alternative using `%l%` from qdapTools package

```
library(qdapTools)
dat$Category <-  dat[,1] %l% unique(dat[complete.cases(dat), ])  
dat
     Name  Category
1   Apple     Fruit
2  Banana     Fruit
3 Cabbage Vegetable
4   Apple     Fruit
5  Orange     Fruit
6 Cabbage Vegetable
7     Toy      Misc
8   Apple     Fruit
```

We can use `lookup` as well from qdapTools package

```
dat$Category <- lookup(dat[,1],  unique(dat[complete.cases(dat), ]))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `dplyr::group_by` and then `tidyr::fill`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  fill(Category) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
  Name    Category 
  <chr>   <chr>    
1 Apple   Fruit    
2 Banana  Fruit    
3 Cabbage Vegetable
4 Apple   Fruit    
5 Orange  Fruit    
6 Cabbage Vegetable
7 Toy     Misc     
8 Apple   Fruit
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cabbage", "Apple", 
"Orange", "Cabbage", "Toy", "Apple"), Category = c("Fruit", "Fruit", 
"Vegetable", NA, "Fruit", NA, "Misc", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I think also - `df1 %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Category = Category[1]) %>% ungroup()`. One less package if that's worth something.

Comment: That is sensitive to the order of the rows whereas `tidyr::fill()` is not.

Answer (score 5):

In base R we can use `match` (which is pretty analogous to excel's `vlookup` that you are familiar with)

```
df1$Category = df1$Category[match(df1$Name, df1$Name)]
```

If you want to generalize to other situations where the value to lookup is not necessarily the first occurrence, we can use

```
lookup = df1[!is.na(df1$Category),]
df1$Category = lookup$Category[match(df1$Name, lookup$Name)]
```